# How to convert the bits in memory to a string of ones and zeros?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a C++ dll written circa 1999 into a modern C++ dll. Apparently there are diffences in how the data is written to memory by the old program (Lotus 123) and how it is read by my modern dll. I'm getting garbage from the return values (outputs -20304 for row count instead of 4). The documentation mentions both C and C++ but I don't suppose that matters since C++ can compile C code anyway.

> Documentation from Lotus 123:
>   Gets the data in a range, referenced as a set of pointers to the contents of individual cells. This method allocates memory for copying the contents of the range, sets the values in memory, and **returns an array pointer that can be used by an external C program**.
>
> Example Description: ...call a **C library function**...
>
> Example Steps: Build the **C++ source code given below** (following the script code) into a DLL. No other files are needed in the project. The DLL exports a function TransposeDoub that transposes an array of doubles.

The following is verbatim from the example code given (written in 1999):

```
' The following is the C++ source code for the transpose routine. 

celld.c

#include <malloc.h>
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )
//
// Cell array header
//
    typedef struct _CellDataHdr {
       unsigned short hdrSize;            // Length of this struct

       unsigned short IsDouble;           // 1 if the following array is double
                                          // 0 if it is vector of char *-s
       unsigned long size;                // Number of elements in the array
       unsigned long rows, cols, sheets;  // Number of rows, columns, and sheets
                                          // Set by GetCellData method... ignored
                                          // Not used by other methods
    } CellDataHdr, *PCellDataHdr;


// The cell array transposition follows this pattern: 
//
//      From ---------------->To
//
//      <--cols-->           <--cols-->
//  ^   A  B  C  D       ^   Q  R  S  T
//  |   E  F  G  H       |   M  N  O  P
// rows I  J  K  L  ==> rows I  J  K  L
//  |   M  N  O  P       |   E  F  G  H
//  v   Q  R  S  T       v   A  B  C  D
//

//
// Transpose a cell array of doubles. 
//
DllExport long TransposeDoub(unsigned long ptr, unsigned long rows, unsigned long cols)

{
   PCellDataHdr hdr = (PCellDataHdr) ptr;
   double *buf = (double *) &hdr[1];
   unsigned int i, j;
   int count = 0;

   // Validate arguments and table. 
   if (rows <= 2 ||
      !hdr->IsDouble ||
      rows > hdr->rows ||
      cols > hdr->cols) {
      return 0;
      }

   for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      double tmp, *pCol;
      pCol = &buf[i * hdr->rows];             // Calc column pointer. 

      // Swap column rows.
      for (j = 0; j < rows/2; j++) {

         tmp = pCol[rows - j - 1];
         pCol[rows - j - 1] = pCol[j];
         pCol[j] = tmp;
         count++;
         }
      }
   return count; 
}
```

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227115/how-to-get-the-header-value-from-long-pointer) I didn't get any definitive help so instead I'd like to try something different. I'd like to look at the actual ones and zeros in memory and try some manual interpretation. Basically I'm trying to see how things are encoded and work backwards to a way to extract the actual data.

How can I convert the bits in memory to a string of ones and zeros in my C++ dll?

Comment: You are probably going a level deeper than you need to.  Simply printing a hex dump of memory would allow analysis if your structure aligns with the actual data correctly.  I suspect there is a structure packing difference between the compilers used around 1999 and those available today.  There are pragmas that can make them behave in a way that would cause the compiled structure image to match what's actually in spreadsheet memory, once you know what's going on.

Comment: @AmardeepAC9MF Thanks a lot; that advice was gold.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of a specific bit of memory by doing the following:

```
//requires bit_num < 8! 
bool is_bit_set(uint8_t byte, int bit_num)
{
    return (byte & (1 << bit_num)) != 0;
}
```

where `<<` is a left bitshift, and `&` is a bitwise AND.

Cast your array of doubles to a uint8_t array, and iterate over the bytes one by one, printing either a 1 or 0 depending on the output of the above function.